# Can Arduino post multiple sensor data to one Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, wireless, documentation

Let's say I have one MQ5 gas sensor at home and one MQ135 gas sensor at the park. They are wirelessly hooked to Arduino.

My questions are:

Can Arduino post the data from two or more sensors to one Google Spreadsheet and organize it in two different charts?

Can only one Arduino accomplish this?

If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps you could do a web search before posting ?

Comment: I do this sort of thing for my solar plant, but I do it by pairing all my arduino-based sensors with a Raspberry Pi via Serial.  I keep the Arduino IDE on the Pi so I can reprogram them remotely via the same cable.  Pis are accessed via WiFi.  The Pis all have Internet access so this wouldn't be difficult to do it that way directly.  Myself, I have each Pi collect the readings into CSV files and also PNG plots (using gnuplot), then at midnight my main Linux machine uploads all the data for formatting.  I can't answer your question directly, but in my case, I do all Internet stuff in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly but with addon service like Pushingbox, temboo and so on it can.

If you google on your topic there are a ton of ways to do it!